# Calling Greasemonkey user.js from a custom Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, firefox-addon

I'm modifying the existing GrabThemAll Firefox extension, which takes a list of URLs, loads them each into their own browser window, and takes a screenshot of the page.

I would also like to run a greasemonkey script on this page, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.  I have GM set up to automatically execute any time the URLs in question are loaded (and it does work when browsing normally), but it seems that the GM extension isn't running when loading the content in its own browser window.

Does anybody have any pointers, or ideas for how to invoke a GM script from within my extension (or to get the browser window to run extensions)?

Comment: I haven't used GrabThemAll before, does it open tabs/windows and take a screenshot? or does it take snapshots in the background some other way?

Comment: It pops open a new dialog and puts a browser component inside it.  This browser is then used to load all of the URLs you wish to take screenshots of, one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/) I think it might work instead of Greasemoneky because it listens to the `"content-document-global-created"` event and GM is listening to new tab opens and tab location changes inside the main browser windows.

If Scriptish isn't running userscripts on te tabs that your extension is opening then you can force it to with code like so:

```
Cc["@scriptish.erikvold.com/scriptish-service;1"].getService().wrappedJSObject.docReady(safeWindow, chromeWindow);
```

where chromeWindow would have `gBrowser` defined, and safeWin is a wrapped content `window`.